# What is the meaning of the conditional expression for checking DrawItemState equivalence in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I was reading the [DrawItemState documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawitemstate?view=netframework-4.7.2) and I encountered the following snippet of code:

```
if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected )
          brush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
```

The following explanation was given in the documentation

> Since state can be a combination (bit-flag) of enum values, you can't
>   use "==" to compare them

However I still do not understand how this conditional expression is different from the snippet shown below:

```
if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected )
          brush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
```

Also, I don't understand how the bitwise AND `&` operator makes a difference and why it is even included in the conditional expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the underlying values of the enum, you can set multiple values ([bitwise combination](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/22/c-fundamentals-combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags.aspx)):

```
var state = DrawItemState.Disabled | DrawItemState.Grayed;
```

That means that these will both return `false`:

```
Console.WriteLine(state == DrawItemState.Disabled);  // false
Console.WriteLine(state == DrawItemState.Grayed);    // false
```

One way to test the values is with the bitwise "and" operator:

```
Console.WriteLine((state & DrawItemState.Grayed) == DrawItemState.Grayed);  // true
```

Essentially, `state` in my example has two bits set - for "Grayed" and "Disabled". By using the bitwise "and" operator with the value of "Grayed", the result is also the value of "Grayed".

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0    // binary value of disabled and grayed

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0    // binary value of grayed

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0    // result is same value as grayed
```

You could test for multiple flags too:

```
Console.WriteLine((state & (DrawItemState.Grayed | DrawItemState.Disabled))
                  == (DrawItemState.Grayed | DrawItemState.Disabled));  // true

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0    // binary value of disabled and grayed

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0    // binary value of disabled and grayed

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0    // result is same value as disabled and grayed
```

Personally, I think it's easier to test for flag values using `HasFlag`:

```
Console.WriteLine(state.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Grayed));  // true
```

Note that if there's just one value, then `==` will work, but for a "flags" enumeration that supports a bitwise combination, that's never a guarantee.

```
var state = DrawItemState.Grayed;

Console.WriteLine(state == DrawItemState.Grayed);  // true
```